# How can I send music from an app to one BT device, but keep all other sounds on another BT device or on the phone?

Tags: rooting, samsung, bluetooth, audio, google-pixel

I am blind, literally, and I use Androids built in screen reader, TalkBack.

When I want to get my jam on, I want to be able to send my tunes to one BT device, and keep all other audio either on the phone or on another BT device.

I used to have a Galaxy S10. My favorite feature was the "Separate App Sounds" option in Samsungs "Sound Assistant" app. It let me do exactly this. Is there any way to do this on other devices?

I have a Pixel 3A XL. I don't mind rooting or installing another rom, so long as it works with my Google Fi E-SIM.

I appreciate any help and ideas. Weather you can help or not, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a samsung.

There hasn't been an answer for nearly 2 weeks, so this flippant one will have to do. Still looking for a better answer.